# PowerShell scriptiong. Как автоматически заполнить пароль для ssh подключения?

Tags: windows, powershell

Хочу написать маленький скрипт, который будет запускать несколько последовательных команд.

Запустить подключение к ssh я понял как, а вот найти информацию о том, как мне заполнить выданное Read-Host поле, не понятно.

Хотелось бы узнать, что нужно написать в скрипте, для того, что бы это поле заполнилось автоматически?

[image: То самое Read-Host поле для ввода пароля, которое появляется когда пытаешься подключиться к хосту]

[image: Вот так скрипт выглядит на данный момент]

Comment: Вместо этого вам стоит настроить ключи ssh и запретить использование пароля.

Comment: А как сделать без ключей и отключения паролей?